# how to pass the value dynamically to sp using java?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, callable-statement

**I want to pass the value to sp parameter dynamically. is it possible with CallableStatement and PreparedStatement?**

```
Connection con=null;
Drivername="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";.
Connectionname="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test;
Class.forName(Drivername);
con = DriverManager.getConnection(Connectionname,USER_NAME, PWD); 
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("sp_help sp_emp_det");
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
List<String> lstint= new ArrayList<String>();
pstmt.getMoreResults(); //returns set of resultset in boolean
rs = pstmt.getResultSet();
while(rs.next())
{
    System.out.println(rs.getString(2)); //checking input parameter list
    lstint.add(rs.getString(2)); // getting list of parameter's datatype from sp and push into Arraylist
}
pstmt = con.prepareStatement("{call sp_emp_det(?,?,?)}");
for (int i=1; i<=lstint.size() ; i++ )
{
pstmt.setString(i,lstValue.get(i-1));
}
rs = pstmt.executeUpdate(); //throws error on here which mentioned below
//to retrive resultset from the sp
while(rs.next())
{
String s=rs.getString(1);
System.out.println("s : "+s);
}
```

**if I use executeUpdate() insteadof executeQuery()
    Execute_SP.java:43: incompatible types
    found   : int
    required: java.sql.ResultSet
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeUpdate();**

if I use executeQuery() above code, it returns the resultset and display the value of s from backend

I'm trying get list of input parameters from sp which works fine and trying to pass the values to the parameters dynamically

list of parameters for the sp

```
Parameter_name Type
@ename         nvarchar
@position      varchar
@expr          int
```

if use below with exceuteUpdate() : which works fine

```
pstmt.setString(1,"");
pstmt.setString(2,"");
pstmt.setInt(3,0);
```

Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Comment: The executeUpdate method returns an int, not a ResultSet -- hence the exception.

Comment: @dsp_user- oh k.. actually I'm trying to pass values from List<String> to the input parameter - sp. In sp, I have below input parameters
**Parameter_name Type
ename                 nvarchar
position                varchar
expr                     int**

but in java
i used to pass the values from List by below code

for (int i=1; i<=lstint.size() ; i++ )
{
pstmt.setString(i,lstValue.get(i-1));
}

now getting error as **com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The value is not set for the parameter number 1.**
on using pstmt.executeQuery() with above code.

Comment: This just means that lstint.size() returns 0 so the code inside the for loop is never executed. What's this PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("sp_help sp_emp_det") supposed to do?

Comment: oh k.. is any other way to bring it?
that statement brings each parameter's datatype in mssql.

Comment: Take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543924/sql-server-2005-metadata-search-to-get-stored-procedure-parameters. The query to retrieve a stored procedure parameters is given so just use that.

Comment: Thanks for ur help @dsp_user. link you shared also useful for me then I have also achieved passing values dynamically by replacing of **pstmt.setString(i,lstValue.get(i-1));** to 
**if(col_type.trim().toLowerCase().equals("nvarchar") || col_type.trim().toLowerCase().equals("varchar"))
{ pstmt=<class_name>.getparamtype(i,'N',lstValue,pstmt); } **
**public static PreparedStatement getparamtype(int ai,Character acol_type,List<String> lstValue,PreparedStatement apstmt) throws SQLException { switch (acol_type)  { case 'N':  apstmt.setString(ai,lstValue.get(ai-1)); break; return apstmt;}**

Comment: Glad you have it working now.

Comment: yeah.. Thanks buddy.. !! :) already did all this.. but insteadof this if(col_type.trim().toLowerCase().equals("varchar")), I used if(col_type=="varchar") so can't achieved.. Once thought differnet. it works fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question. 
pstmt.executeUpdate() just return row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements.

Comment: if we set parameter value one by one like 
**pstmt.setString(1,"");pstmt.setString(2,"");pstmt.setInt(3,0);** which works fine. but i'm trying to pass value to the parameters dynamically to sp. please see the error with executeQuery() which commented to dsp_user. you can suggest any other way.. will try and check it.